# Do you charge for a client for your time if they don't like the work or at least they say they don't?

Tags: billable-hours

i have a client who wants a design job for a product launch> This is a new client for me and a new line of work. I have a freelancer who will do the work, but how do I charge.

it is easy if the client likes the work, but do you charge for your time if they don't like the work or at least they say they don't?

How do you ask for them to pay for something they are not even certain they are going to like.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, the freelance conundrum!

It's obviously impossible to know if somebody will like or dislike something as subjective as design. However there are a few things you can do to minimise the risk:

First, get as much information pre-project as possible. Put together a questionnaire that answers questions about their target audience, competitors and how they want to position themselves in the market.

This will give you clues on how your designs need to look. Remember, you're probably not designing for just one persons taste, you're designing to solve some sort of problem and appeal to a group of people.

If you can justify your design choices using the information gathered in your questionnaire you should be fine.

The second thing you can do is add another stage to the project where you put together a few style moodboards. This is handy for you but you can also send over to the client to check your visions align. Don't be shy to ask them to contribute - make it a collaboration.

The third thing is very important and covers you if after all that they still don't like what you've produced (and worst of all but very rare - refuse to pay!)

You need to clearly state in your quote (not in teeny writing at the bottom mind!) that this project comes with x- sets of amends. I usually find 2 is plenty.

You must also request a deposit (50% is always good) before any work begins so of the client does a runner at least you have half.

If you follow the above steps, and sorry for the lack of formatting - I can't seem to do that on my phone, you are minimising the risk of a. Client not liking your work and b. Not getting paid.

Best of luck!